# How to upload a file and body params simultaneously in postman

Tags: api, file-upload, postman

I am trying to upload a file and passing some body params with request.but getting error while passing.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: body params or query params? Do you have api docs?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17  Added the docs image in question.It is given in docs as request params and file is given in json format..I tried that also..But didnt get response.

Comment: It's not clear how to build the request. I guess putting all params in `form-data` tab `body`, not in tab `Params` .